Enum flags OR ways and their compilation result
Nothing more than curiosity here.
Let's say I have a normal enum of flags:
[Flags]
public enum MyFlags
{
    None = 0,
    A = 0x01,
    B = 0x02,
    C = 0x04,
    D = 0x08,
}

Then, two different ways to achieve the same operation:
public class C {
    public void M1() {
        MyFlags flags = MyFlags.A;
        flags |= MyFlags.B | MyFlags.C | MyFlags.D;
        Console.WriteLine((int)flags);
    }
    
    public void M2() {
        MyFlags flags = MyFlags.A;
        flags |= MyFlags.B;
        flags|= MyFlags.C;
        flags|= MyFlags.D;
        Console.WriteLine((int)flags);
    }
}

Note that the Console.WriteLine has no importance in the subject.
What surprises me is the generated C# as Release using SharpLab:
public class C
{
    public void M1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1 | 0xE);
    }

    public void M2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(7 | 8);
    }
}

Both are correct, of course. However, whereas the first form could be expectable, I can't understand how the compiler outputs the second form.
Why leaving the last OR operation out, instead of aggregating to the previous?
There's more. If I inspect the IL (still Release), the result seems getting worse:
// Methods
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void M1 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 10 (0xa)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.s 14
    IL_0003: or
    IL_0004: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_0009: ret
} // end of method C::M1

.method public hidebysig 
    instance void M2 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x205b
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.2
    IL_0002: or
    IL_0003: ldc.i4.4
    IL_0004: or
    IL_0005: ldc.i4.8
    IL_0006: or
    IL_0007: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method C::M2

Interestingly, the JIT-ed ASM looks the perfection!
C.M1()
    L0000: mov ecx, 0xf
    L0005: call dword ptr [0x207a72b8]
    L000b: ret

C.M2()
    L0000: mov ecx, 0xf
    L0005: call dword ptr [0x207a72b8]
    L000b: ret

Why the generated code of the second form is so different for the three cases?

It's the last operation inlined. flags |= MyFlags.B | MyFlags.C | MyFlags.D produces 1 | 0xE because flags had value 1 and on the right side several flags were combined to 0xE. And flags|= MyFlags.D; produces 7 | 8 similarly.

Given that a .NET "compilation result" comes from 2 phases: compilation to MSIL, then jitting to machine code, my guess is that the first is the result of constant evaluation by the C# compiler while the second is a result of common sub-expression elimination (or something something similar) by the jitter.  The results are similar but take a different path to get there.
